# How was the concubine of givah killed

Tags: women, shoftim--book-of

What [killed](https://www.sefaria.org/Judges.19.28?with=Rashi&lang=bi) the concubine of givah.
What is the natural explanation.

It does not seem natural that mass rape can kill someone overnight.

Source please

Comment: I would argue that it was a combination of both physical and mental exhaustion coupled with mass stress and fear. Also, the Tanach doesn't describe what was exactly done to her - you know, step by step - so it's entirely possible, perhaps even probable - that a rough group of men would act severely violent towards her, further adding to the weakness that came from the situation.

Comment: @Harel13 it seems  commentaries only bring that she was raped not any other damage  https://www.sefaria.org/Judges.19.25?with=Commentary&lang=bi

Comment: Well, rape often includes violent acts--one does not need to look at it as a separate act, but as part of the rape itself. So you could say it was "just" rape - but what did *that rape include?* I would therefore say all that I wrote in my above comment.

Comment: It is certainly possible that the rape killed her. For example, during wartime, enemy soldiers would sometimes rape women til dead. This evil act is probably responsible for her death. I agree with @Harel13.

Comment: @TurkHill source please

Comment: I read it somewhere in Bill O'Reilly's book, Killing the Rising Sun.

Comment: it seems it does not happen overnight https://www.thesun.co.uk/news/9847250/india-rape-girl-dead-friends-birthday/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On verse [19:26](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Judges.19.26?lang=bi&with=Metzudat%20David&lang2=en) the Metzudat David states that she died from the exhaustion of the multiple raping.

> **ותפול**. מחמת חולשת **רוב הבעילות** נפלה בפתח ולא הוסיפה לקום, ושכבה עד אור הבוקר, **ומתה**:‏

He says the same thing later in [20:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Judges.20.5?lang=bi&with=Metzudat%20David&lang2=en):

> **ותמת**. מרוב בעילות האונס:‏